# Complement of the space of analytic functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ be the space of functions $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ with derivatives at all orders endowed with the topology of compact convergence of all the derivatives i.e. defined by the seminorms ($n\in \mathbb{N}, \alpha\in \mathbb{N}^2$ and $B$ a bounded open subset)
$$
p_{\,n,B}=sup_{\ 0\leq |\alpha|\leq n\atop t\in B}|D^\alpha(f)[t]|\ . 
$$
I know that the subspace $C^\omega(\mathbb{C})\subset C^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ (analytic functions on all $\mathbb{C}$, called entire functions) is complete and then closed.

> Q1) Is there a known closed complement of it i.e. a decomposition
>   $$
> C^\infty(\mathbb{C})=C^\omega(\mathbb{C})\oplus W
> $$
>   where $W$ is closed ?
>
> Q2) Can we replace the whole $\mathbb{C}$ by a domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: For what topology do you think $C^\omega$ is complete ?

Comment: For the topology induced by that of $C^\infty$, I think.

Comment: Then what makes you think the limit of an analytic sequence is analytic ? For example what if $f_n(x) = \varphi \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ where $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ ?

Comment: Hmm... What is an analytic function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: An entire function but the title is done to match with Q2 as well.

Comment: Then what is $f^j(z)$ ?

Comment: j-iest derivative. I put brackets for the hasty reader.

Comment: You don't see the [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) for non complex analytic functions ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I'll come to this after satisfactory answer (or insight) to my question(s) ?

Comment: ??? Until now your question doesn't make sense. Complex differentiable functions is different to real differentiable functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62342/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-reuns).

Comment: I think it does now (with the multi-index notation).

Comment: @reuns The is a structural [obstruction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277119/is-this-closed-subspace-of-fr%c3%a9chet-space-complemented)

Comment: You were supposed to start with $C^\omega(\Omega)$ the real analytic functions on $\Omega$. And see what happens when taking the closure for the smooth topology (obtaining $C^\infty(\Omega)$), trying to see if the operator I defined is uniformly continuous/bounded on $C^\omega(\Omega)$ and if it can be extended to the closure.

Comment: Also you were supposed to mention my operator, as it is what you want to extend to a larger space than the polynomials. Finally, you didn't say why you want to look at this. Finding motivating examples (avoiding complicated theoretical terminology as you do in your questions) is one of the most important thing in maths.

Comment: After all, I accepted your very very partial answer (and very loose ending :). What counts in this epilogue is that we have learned some structural property which answers more completely my question and, for the time being, complies with my expectations (as I told you, this question, although interesting for me, is not central in my research). So all is well that ends well. I am satisfied and can continue my present studies.

Comment: In gave my motivation in the MO question.

Comment: I don't agree you motivated anything. Also I'm not convinced the answer on MO is adapted to the real question : can we extend my operator to some larger spaces ? from a Fourier series we can easily extract the holomorphic part (bounded in $L^2$ norm). So we should be able to extend my operator for some norms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63146/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-reuns).

Comment: And the MO answer suggests the operator is unbounded for the $\bigcup_k C^k$ semi-norm so the answer should be a sequence proving it.

Comment: [So we should be able to extend my operator for some norms]---> if you are interested, please do it (and tell me :). I, myself, stated this problem which lives exactly as I wrote it within Fréchet spaces (as I wrote them), so there is no projector in general.

Comment: You can't be satisfied by this. You need a sequence showing (how) the operator is unbounded. By the way $\Im( \log (z))$ is smooth on $D \setminus [0,1]$ (and harmonic) and it seems natural its holomorphic part is $\frac{\log z}{2i}$ (unbounded at $z=0$)

Answer (score 1):

We consider the $\sup$ norm.

- By convolution with the Gaussian kernel $g_n(x,y)=n^2 e^{-\pi n^2(x^2+y^2)}$ the bounded real analytic functions on $|x+iy| < r$ are dense in the continuous functions on $|x+iy | \le r$, thus the polynomials in $x,y$ are dense too.
- A polynomial $f(x+iy) = \sum_{n+m \le N} a_{n,m} x^n y^m$ is [complex analytic iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) $$\partial_x f = \sum_{n+m \le N,n\ge 1} a_{n,m} n x^{n-1} y^m = -i\partial_y f = -i\sum_{n+m \le N,m\ge 1} a_{n,m} x^{n} m y^{m-1}$$ ie. iff $n a_{n,m-1} = -i m a_{n-1,m}$ ie. $a_{k-m,m} = a_{k,0} {k \choose m}i^m$
- The polynomial $$h(x+iy) = \sum_{k\le N} (x+iy)^k  \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{m=0}^{k} \frac{a_{k-m,m}}{ {k \choose m}i^m}$$

  is complex-analytic and if $f$ was complex analytic then $f=h$.
- The map $T : f \mapsto h$ is $\mathbb{C}$ linear and it is a projection : the polynomials are the direct sum of $\text{Im}(T)$
  (complex analytic part) and $\text{ker}(T)$ (the non-complex analytic part).
- The complex analytic functions are closed for the uniform convergence on compacts, so taking the closure for some norms or semi-norms you can extend this decomposition for the continuous functions or the $C^\infty$ functions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll return to you if needed.

Comment: [The complex analytic functions ... you can extend this decomposition ...]---> I surmise it that you use some standard theorem, what is it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more the end ? (answer without Hmm ... and ???? required :)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. What did you try ?

Comment: All this game does not help me much. So either you know the complete solution (and more precisely than the loose "... some norms or semi-norms ... ") and help me or not and tell it honestly. After all, maybe $C^\omega(\mathbb{C})$ that is not complemented within $C^\infty(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Are you serious ? Do you remember our discussion ? Help you for what ?

Comment: I see that we don't understand each other, this is not a problem for me. Thank you for your efforts so far nevertheless.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I asked what did you try, and you didn't show some efforts. So given everything we wrote, what is the problem you really want to solve or investigate, do you have some simpler cases or relevant examples, and where are you stuck ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62558/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-reuns).

Comment: Finally, there is a structural [obstruction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277119/is-this-closed-subspace-of-fr%c3%a9chet-space-complemented)

Comment: In fact, I did not quite understand the structural obstruction and am wondering if the Cauchy-Pompeiu formula (look at generalizations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)) could not be a way of removing the non-complex analytic part of the general smooth functions. But I am not an expert in these matters.